# How to redirect to an alias folder using htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a url http://www.example.com/chatroom/chats.php?chat=hey dear

I want a url to be http://www/example.com/chatroom/chats/hey dear

where chatroom is an alias folder.

my apache document root is pointing to a specific folder as DocumentRoot

`/var/www/html/myweb`

I am trying like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^chatroom/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ chats.php?chat=$1 [NC]
```

Its saying

> 404 not found.

Answer (score 1):

Set **QSA** flag for your rule and try

```
RewriteRule ^chatroom/(.*) chats.php?chat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

QSA - Query String Append

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a .htaccess file in chatroom folder with the following content.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule chats/(.*) chats.php?chat=$1
```

Or the following if placing in root folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /chatroom/chats.php?chat=$1 [L]
```

Here are some tools which might help you to generate the such code.

[http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php](https://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php)

[http://www.webconfs.com/web-tools/url-rewriting-tool/](https://www.webconfs.com/web-tools/url-rewriting-tool/)

Comment: I tried with solution you given but didn't work. I also tried with htaccess generator you suggested. The requested URL /chatroom/chats/looking-fwd-to-new-offer was not found on this server.

Comment: In my localhost I am able to achieve the desired url format. Its on test server where is not taking. I think its path issue where I am doing wrong. On my local machine its taking full path where on test server it starting with /chatroom/blashblah

Comment: http://localhost/testme/question/newqust. Its woking fine on my local. I am able to get the newques in my chats.php.

Comment: I figured it out. Issue was on url it contains special characters and I was not handling in htacces file. anyway thanks for the help @Samay